# Returning a malloc'd pointer from a C++ object

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc

I'm working on refactoring legacy C code using C++, and am doing it piecemeal because of the amount of code that needs refactoring.  The refactored C++ code is building LegacyCAttribute structs via malloc and value retrieval strategies.  The non-refactored code still uses the old LegacyCAttribute structs.

If I return a stack variable within the get strategy to the calling code, all is fine.  But if I make the LegacyCAttribute* a member variable of the ValueStrategy class, the calling code core dumps.

This code works ok:

```
class ValueStrategy {
public:
    LegacyCAttribute* get();
};

LegacyCAttribute* ValueStrategy::get()
{
    LegacyCAttribute* attr = malloc(sizeof(LegacyCAttribute));
    // Build attr here by malloc'ing more memory for attr value lists and values etc.
    return attr;
}
```

This causes a core dump in the get caller when it tries to use the pointer returned by the get:

```
class ValueStrategy {
public:
    LegacyCAttribute* get();
    LegacyCAttribute* m_attr;
};

LegacyCAttribute* ValueStrategy::get()
{
    m_attr = malloc(sizeof(LegacyCAttribute));
    // Build m_attr here by malloc'ing more memory for attr value lists and values etc.
    return m_attr;
}
```

I know m_attr is going away when ValueStrategy object is destructed, but the memory that was allocated using malloc() that it points to is not getting free'd in that destruction, so I don't understand why the calling code crashes using the pointer returned by the get() call in the 2nd case and not the 1st.

Correction - the 2nd version of the code actually does work - it was core dumping because the code was actually:

```
LegacyCAttribute* ValueStrategy::get()
{
    if (m_attr == NULL)
    {
        m_attr = malloc(sizeof(LegacyCAttribute));
        // Build m_attr here by malloc'ing more memory for attr value lists and values etc.
    }
    return m_attr;
}
```

an I was not initializing m_attr to NULL in the ValueStrategy ctor.

Thank you to all who responded you are Awesome!  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: What is the value of the pointer m_attr when it crashed ? Could you show the calling code ?

Comment: Ahhh...  I looked at it again in an attempt to provide more info, and realized I was not initializing m_attr to NULL in the ValueStrategy ctor, and the code in the get() was therefore not calling the malloc because m_attr was not NULL!  This code actually does work.  Doh!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Classes in C++ are by default copyable. If they contain pointers, the pointers are copied but not what they point to. If the destructor of one of the class instances then invokes `delete` on the pointer (or free()), it will leave the other copy with a "dangling pointer" that will later on cause all kinds of headache.

That said, please provide the real code, distilled down to a small but complete example. In particular `LegacyCAttribute* attr = malloc(sizeof(LegacyCAttribute));` will not compile as C++, as it lacks a `static_cast`. Well, unless `LegacyCAttribute` is actually an alias for `void`, but the complete example will show that. :)

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, I found the bug while I was trying to write a short example program, and it wasn't where I expected (see other comment responses).